# Binding the list of checkbox to a Dictionary in datamodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, checkbox, model

I'm new to MVC3 and I can't understand how to use checkboxes.
In my model I have a list of Services and a list of available Services.
The idea is to display all available services and let user to select which once to use ba checking the corresponding checkbox.

```
public Activity()
        {
            .....
            this.Services = new List<Service>();
            this.ServicesChecklist = new Dictionary<Service, bool>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Service, bool> ServicesChecklist { get; set; }
```

I was able to load the service table properly using the private method of the Controller
            private Dictionary AssignServiceToActivity(Activity activity)
            {

```
            List<Service> s = new List<Service>(db.Services);
            Dictionary<Service, bool> ServicesChecklist = new Dictionary<Service, bool>();
            bool found;


            foreach (var ser in s)
            {
                found = false;
                foreach (var currService in activity.Services)
                {
                    if (ser.id == currService.id)
                    {
                        ServicesChecklist.Add(ser, true);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                    ServicesChecklist.Add(ser, false);
            }
            return ServicesChecklist;
        }


in my view I am trying to bind the checkboxes to the ServicesChecklist dictionary

<div id="tabs-2">
         <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Service
               </th>
               <th>
                  Type
               </th>
               <th>
                  Contact
               </th>
               <th>
                  Phone
               </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var s in @Model.ServicesChecklist)
            {
            <tr>
               <td>

                  @Html.CheckBox(s.Key.name, s.Key.id) 
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.Key.name)                  
                </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.Key.ServiceType.name)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.Key.contact_name)
               </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.Key.contact_phone)
               </td>

            </tr>
            }
         </table>
      </div>
```

It works fine when the page loaded but user selection is not saved in the model

```
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buklf.png
```

Comment: See this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024034/i-lost-my-data-on-submit-mvc-3), which should provide an answer to your problem, as well as the background behind what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a form with a submit button to submit the changes back to the server or use JavaScript to submit three changes back when a change event occurs.